# How do I use gdb to debug a stack segmentation fault?

Tags: linux, debugging, assembly, gdb, nasm

I wrote this simple program in NASM, I know that Linux ends the program when the stack grows into the program code, but how would I debug such an issue in a real scenario, obviously ignoring the fact that this should never happen.

```
section .data

section .bss

section .text
global _start
_start:
        nop
        mov eax,42
        SillyLoop:      push eax
                        jmp SillyLoop
        nop
```

When I run gdb I receive

```
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
SillyLoop () at sandbox.asm:10
```

This is not very helpful, how do I extract more information (in a real program)?

Comment: I'd recommend running the program through `valgrind`. It would tell you the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is not very helpful, how do I extract more information (in a real program)?

You can examine the call stack using `where` command (not going to help here, since there is only one routine on the stack), and examine the current faulting instruction using `x/i $pc`. Given:

```
(gdb) x/i $pc
=> 0x8049006 <SillyLoop>:       push   %eax
```

you can *immediately* tell that there is something wrong with the stack (since that's the *only* reason a `PUSH` can fail) -- either your `ESP` has been screwed up, or you've run out of stack. Examining stack pointer with `info reg esp` (which prints `0xff7fe000`) provides another clue: you are on a page boundary.

But in the end, programming in assembly is like using a very sharp knife -- you need to know what you are doing, or you can write a program that will be hard to debug.